# QWebSettings in PyQt5 (version 5.6.0)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, conda, qtwebkit

I have `PyQt5` (version 5.6.0) installed via Anaconda on my Mac (OS X 10.12.2). Now I would like to re-use an older script that used `QtWebKitWidgets`and `QtWebKit`, however, these two packages seem to have been removed in `PyQt5.6.0`. I already know that `QtWebKitWidgets` was replaced by `QtWebEngineWidgets` (which all works fine for me), but in my old code, I was importing `QWebSettings` from `QtWebKit`, i.e.

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
```

But not I get an ImportError here:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKit'
```

According to the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets),

> `QtWebEngineWidgets` contains classes for a Chromium based implementation 
>   of a web browser. This supercedes the `QtWebKit` module and provides better and up-to-date support for HTML, CSS and JavaScript features. However it also consumes more resources and doesn’t give direct access to the network stack and the HTML document via Python APIs.

But where do I find `QWebSettings`? Can anyone please tell me where I can find `QWebSettings`now, or how I can add the package `QtWebKit`?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [QWebEngineSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html).

Comment: That's it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The correct import statement is:

`from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings`

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'